Unable to get all users from Microsoft Graph using Python SDK
I need to know user emails and id (so I can identify the user from the email).
According to Microsoft documentation, the below code should allow the retrival of user information.
import asyncio
import configparser

from azure.identity.aio import ClientSecretCredential
from msgraph import GraphServiceClient
from msgraph.generated.users.item.user_item_request_builder import UserItemRequestBuilder

def main():
    # Load settings
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read(['config.cfg', 'config.dev.cfg'])
    azure_settings = config['azure']

    credentials = ClientSecretCredential(
        azure_settings['tenantId'],
        azure_settings['clientId'],
        azure_settings['clientSecret'],
    )
    scopes = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default']
    client = GraphServiceClient(credentials=credentials, scopes=scopes)
    query_params = UserItemRequestBuilder.UserItemRequestBuilderGetQueryParameters(select=['id', 'mail', ])

    request_config = UserItemRequestBuilder.UserItemRequestBuilderGetRequestConfiguration(query_parameters=query_params)
    users = asyncio.run(client.users.get(request_config))
    print(users)


However, I get the error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\ProcessEmailReceipts\microsoft_graph.py", line 35, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\ProcessEmailReceipts\microsoft_graph.py", line 28, in main
    request_config = UserItemRequestBuilder.UserItemRequestBuilderGetRequestConfiguration(query_parameters=query_params)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: type object 'UserItemRequestBuilder' has no attribute 'UserItemRequestBuilderGetRequestConfiguration'

Looking at the repo, that class does indeed not exists.
Is there a way to get all users id and emails with the python sdk?
Thanks,

Initially, register one Entra ID application and grant User.Read.All permission of Application type as below:

To get all the users with ID and Emails using MS Graph Python SDK, make use of below sample code:
import asyncio
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from msgraph import GraphServiceClient

tenant_id = "tenantID"
client_id = "appID"
client_secret = "secret"

credential = ClientSecretCredential(
    tenant_id=tenant_id,
    client_id=client_id,
    client_secret=client_secret
)

client = GraphServiceClient(credential)

async def main():
    result = await client.users.get()
    users = result.value

    for user in users:
        print("User ID:", user.id)
        print("User Email:", user.mail)
        print("User Display Name:", user.display_name)
        print("-" * 50)  # Separating each user with a line

asyncio.run(main())

Response:

Reference:
List users - Microsoft Graph

Thank you for your answer, didn't realize I can skip all the config. I will test it and then accept the answer

Answer from Sridevi works, but there are four important things:

If testing on Windows, Enable Long Paths. Then run PowerShell as administrator and run:

New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem" -Name "LongPathsEnabled" -Value 1 -PropertyType DWORD -Force


Install all required modules:

pip3 install msal azure-identity msgraph-sdk asyncio msgraph-core


If you are getting "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation." error, go to API Permissions page in EntraID registered application and verify there is no error hanging there, which might require approval. Make sure to click on Grant admin consent for XXXXXX button on the API Permissions page.

Make sure you did not provide Delegated type, but Application type permissions. Delegated will not work.


An alternative way to Query MS Graph API in Python is described here.
Note, that to test this exact scenario, you need also Group.Read.All, also with Application type, not Delegated type permissions. If you'd like to list users, replace:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups

with:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users

Code from link:
Obtaining access token
# Define imports
import msal

# Enter the details of your AAD app registration
client_id = '{YOUR CLIENT ID}'
client_secret = '{YOUR CLIENT SECRET}'
authority = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{YOUR TENANT ID}'
scope = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default']

# Create an MSAL instance providing the client_id, authority and client_credential parameters
client = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(client_id, authority=authority, client_credential=client_secret)

# First, try to lookup an access token in cache
token_result = client.acquire_token_silent(scope, account=None)

# If the token is available in cache, save it to a variable
if token_result:
  access_token = 'Bearer ' + token_result['access_token']
  print('Access token was loaded from cache')

# If the token is not available in cache, acquire a new one from Azure AD and save it to a variable
if not token_result:
  token_result = client.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scope)
  access_token = 'Bearer ' + token_result['access_token']
  print('New access token was acquired from Azure AD')

print(access_token)

Querying MS Graph using client_id and secret
# Define imports
import requests

# Copy access_token and specify the MS Graph API endpoint you want to call, e.g. 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups' to get all groups in your organization
access_token = '{ACCESS TOKEN YOU ACQUIRED PREVIOUSLY}'
url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups'
headers = {
  'Authorization': access_token
}

# Make a GET request to the provided url, passing the access token in a header
graph_result = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)

# Print the results in a JSON format
print(graph_result.json())

